# Why Are My DynamoDB Items With a TTL Epoch Not Deleting?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, ttl

**Two epoch dates that are in the past by greater than one week:**

1. 1666324555879
2. 1666170554391

I have determined their date with this tool: https://www.epochconverter.com/

**Expectation:** Items to delete within 48 hours of the epoch date, determined by the field with (TTL) in it.

**Outcome:** No items in any table deleting.

**Records in the Console:**

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

DynamoDB expects the TTL value to be [in seconds](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/time-to-live-ttl-before-you-start.html#time-to-live-ttl-before-you-start-formatting), but yours are in *milliseconds*.

Your items will be deleted in about 50k years ;)